# How to limit the remote port (server side) when tunneling through SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, sshd

How do I configure my sshd to limit the port the client can tunnel to?

example:

A is client and B is server

A executes ssh -L local-port:localhost:remote-port user@B

B needs to be able to deny the tunneling if the remote port does not match a fixed value

Is this possible in ssh?

I tried

```
PermitOpen localhost:port
```

and

```
PermitListen port
```

inside sshd configuration but they didn't seem to work. But I'm not sure this is the right syntax.

Comment: There's not much point to this. Anybody can get a specific local port at their end. There is no security in this kind of rule. And `PermitListen` restricts local listening ports, not remote ports, as it states in the documentation. Off topic.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. would you mind expanding on why it wouldn't increase security?  If I had multiple services on loopback and I wanted userA to access only one instance on one port why wouldn't limiting the remote port locally be a security feature?

Comment: Would you mind expanding on why you think it *would* increase security? In the light of what I have *already* said? How is it going to stop an attacker? SSH already has tons of security built-in: after all the guy first has to authenticate. You're not adding anything to that.